# Google Spreadsheet turn off autosave via script?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm fairly new to using Google Docs, but I have come to really appreciate it. The scripting is pretty easy to accomplish simple tasks, but I have come to realize a potential speed issue that is a little frustrating.

I've got a sheet that I use for my business to calculate the cost of certain materials on a jobsite. It works great, but was a little tedious to clear between jobs so I wrote a simple script to clear the ranges (defined by me and referenced by name) that I needed emptied.

Once again, worked great. The only problem with it is that clearing a few ranges (seven) ends up taking about ten full seconds. I -believe- that this is because the spreadsheet is being saved after each range is cleared, which becomes time intensive.

What I'd like to do is test this theory by disabling autosave in the script, and then re enabling it after the ranges have been cleared. I don't know if this is even possible because I haven't seen a function in the API to do it, but if it is I'd love to know about it.

---

Edit: this is the function I'm using as it stands. I've tried rewriting it a couple of times to be more concise and less API call intensive, but so far I haven't had any luck in reducing the time it takes to process the calls.

```
function clearSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("client").clear();
  sheet.getRange("lm_group_1").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("lm_group_2").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("dr_group_1").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("dr_group_2").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("fr_group_1").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("fr_group_2").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("gr_group_1").clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("client_name").activate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, and will probably never be. It's not "the nature" for Google Docs.

But depending on how you wrote your script, it's probable that all changes are already being wrote at once, in the end. There's some API calls that may be forcing a flush of your writings to the spreadsheet (like trying to read after you wrote something), but we'd need to see your code to check that.

Anyway, you can always check the spreadsheet revision history to verify if it's being done at once or in multiple steps.

About the performance, Apps Scripts have a natural delay that is unavoidable, but it's not 10s, so there's probably room to improve on your script, using fewer API calls and preferring batch calls like `setValues` over `setValue` and so on. But then again, we'd have to see your code to assert that and give more helpful tips.

Comment: I've added my current script to the original post. I _hate_ it as it stands now (too many API calls) and will likely rewrite it anyways to be a bit more elegant, but this is it's state as work-in-progress.